# PreparedStatement parameters to be reused as CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, common-table-expression, mybatis

Considering this simplified query in a `PreparedStatement` form

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table 
WHERE 
   col_x IN (?, ?, ?) 
OR col_y IN (?, ?, ?)
OR col_z IN (?, ?, ?)
```

where we need to set the same values from a Java collection three times (say `List.of(1, 2, 3)`, MyBatis doing the hard work in ). Is there a way to rewrite the query in a way to set it only once instead of three times? I was thinking something with CTE and then JOINing instead of IN for isntance but can't figure it out (other then executing it as 3 separate queries and merging results).

The story is:
The collection can have up to 1000 values and because of the this query + model design we hit SQL Server limit of 2100 parameters now and then and get

> SQLServerException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request

Comment: Use a table type parameter. But also, doing this type of query against many columns seems like you might have a design flaw as well. Difficult to know with the overly simplified example.

Comment: the design .. story for another day. what would the table type parameter look like? I just found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 which could be uset in CTE

Comment: [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

The WITH option:

```
WITH prms(p) AS(
   select ? union all
   select ? union all
   select ? 
)
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table 
WHERE col_x IN (select p from prms)
   OR col_y IN (select p from prms)
   OR col_z IN (select p from prms)
```

Comment: yes, this works as well, yielding the same result as the Table value constructor

Answer (score 1):

I typically use a single-row CTE and then I cross-join it in the main query(ies). Since it's a single-row CTE it can be cross-joined in multiple CTEs, subqueries, and/or in the main query, as needed.

For example:

```
with params (x, y, z) as (
  select ?, ?, ?
)
select a, b, c
from table
cross join params p
where col_x in (p.x, p.y, p.z)
   or col_y in (p.x, p.y, p.z)
   or col_z in (p.x, p.y, p.z)
```

Comment: that is an interesting one .. I didn't think this could work with the values as separate columns, I always though of it in the way of getting the values as rows in a single colum. But it works, just under the column limit in our case (1024 in SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! It helped me getting in the right direction. I found [Table Value constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the docs for SQL Server which seem a great fit for the CTE and can be easily used as INNER JOIN instead of the IN conditions.

```
WITH params (id) AS (
    SELECT p.id FROM VALUES ((?),(?),(?)) p(id)
)
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table 
JOIN params ON  
   (col_x = params.id OR col_y = params.id OR col_z = params.id)
```

WARNING: Using JOIN might result in returning duplicated rows if more than one value satisfies the ON conditions.

Comment: Note JOIN may return doubles from `table` .

Comment: you are right, technically. Not an issue in my case. I will update the answer to point it out